# MS Word mail merge: A field calculation error occurred in record #

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge, mergefield

[image]

The expected outcome:
1: Amy
2: Bob
3: Carol

4: Dan
5: Eva
6: Eva

7: Fiona

That's why I made use of "{ MERGESEQ }" to have every three records as a section. But it appears to be a calculation error in mail merging every record.

Comment: Is your list separator "," or ";" - you will get a syntax error if you use the wrong one. Thought I'd covered that in my Answer to your previous question, but just wonder if a bit of cut-and-paste has prevented a solution

Comment: Alert box: 'Word could not merge the main document with the data source because the data records were empty or no data records matched your query options.'

Comment: @slightlysnarky You're right. I started a new document, linked to the source (a CSV file with a comma separator) and typed the field codes again. It works. Yet, strangely enough, I typed commands rather than copied and pasted last time. So I bet it was due to the list separator ';' that differs from the comma-CSV file. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The list separator problem is to do with your Windows settings, not the separator in the data source. I put this in my answer to your other question but it seems to have had the opposite effect to what I intended!

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the Windows settings. I found the list separator.